# Preserve script newlines stdout called from Makefile

Tags: bash, makefile

I need from a Makefile echo multilines script stdout::

```
$ more Makefile
mydir:
    a=$(shell ls -la)
    echo "$(a)"
```

So I would like to have::

```
$ make mydir
total 12
drwxrwxr-x  2 luis luis 4096 nov.   6 18:55 .
drwxrwxr-x 14 luis luis 4096 nov.   6 18:45 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 luis luis   40 nov.   6 18:55 Makefile
$
```

But I get::

```
$ make mydir
a=total 12 drwxrwxr-x  2 luis luis 4096 nov.   6 18:55 . drwxrwxr-x 14 luis luis 4096 nov.   6 18:45 .. -rw-rw-r--  1 luis luis   40 nov.   6 18:55 Makefile
/bin/sh: 1: 12: not found
Makefile:2 : la recette pour la cible « mydir » a échouée
make: *** [mydir] Erreur 127
```

By the way my real script has a name with minus like this `my-script-aa`

this post gave not Makefile result:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72724/how-can-i-preserve-new-lines-coming-from-a-commands-output-during-variable-assi

I'm using `GNU bash, version 4.3.46` and `GNU Make 4.1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you using the `shell` make function, when you are already in a shell (because you're in a recipe)?

Try:

```
mydir:
        a=$$(ls -la); echo "$$a"
```

Note that this is equivalent to running these commands at the shell prompt:

```
a=$(ls -la); echo "$a"
```

but we escape the `$` (by typing it twice) so that `make` doesn't interpret it.